# Get content of a buffer

Tags: elisp, buffers, excursion, string

So `buffer-string` gets the content of the current buffer. But it doesn't allow specifying other buffers.

How can I get around that? Do I need something like `save-window-excursion` to make it work?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @King I'm creating an asynchronous process and I want to send buffer's content as it's standard input. I figured I can use `process-send-string` and I got stuck.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

A lot of things in Emacs operate on the current buffer. You need to change the current buffer and restore it when you're done. Use [`with-current-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html#index-with_002dcurrent_002dbuffer-2122) for simple cases where you just need to do something in another buffer, and [`save-current-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html#index-save_002dcurrent_002dbuffer-2123) for more complex cases where you need to navigate between several buffers.

```
(defun buffer-string* (buffer)
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (buffer-string)))
```

If you want the text content of the buffer without properties, call [`buffer-substring-no-properties`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-Contents.html#index-buffer_002dsubstring_002dno_002dproperties-2825).

`buffer-string` returns only the [narrowed](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Narrowing.html#Narrowing) part of the buffer. If you need the whole content, widen it after saving the narrowing.

```
(defun buffer-whole-string (buffer)
  (with-current-buffer buffer
    (save-restriction
      (widen)
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

If you also need to save the point, call [`save-excursion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Excursions.html#index-save_002dexcursion-2759) as well. Note that `save-excursion` restores the point only in the current buffer, so if you need to switch to another buffer and move around there, call `save-excursion` inside `save-current-buffer` or `with-current-buffer`.